# Vertical Line in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Does visual studio provide a functionality to visualise vertical line among the code?
Notepad++ has this functionality.

[image]

Comment: yes it does give the feature with the help of addons

Answer (score 0):

Install this addon in your VS.NET

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30

Comment: What is your experience when you used this addons